# Unable to run pods on new node

Tags: kubernetes

Had to change node (server) with the new one leaving the **same node name**. What I did was:

- master> kubectl delete no srv1 (removing old node)
- srv1> kubeadm join... (joining new node)

after new node joined cluster no pods can be created.

```
Warning  FailedCreatePodSandBox  16s               kubelet, srv1  Failed create pod sandbox: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to set up sandbox container "b85728b51a18533e9d57f6a1b1808dbb5ad72bff4d516217de04e7dad4ce358d" network for pod "dpl-6f56777485-6jzm6": NetworkPlugin cni failed to set up pod "dpl-6f56777485-6jzm6_default" network: failed to set bridge addr: "cni0" already has an IP address different from 10.244.16.1/24
```

Comment: Did you evict the pods `kubectl drain node` and `kubeadm reset`  from the old node? before deleting it ?

Comment: I just done `kubectl delete no srv1`. Is it a cause?

Comment: I think so because API server still thinks there is another weavenet (or similar) pod which is been assigned to that ip

Comment: How can I fix it on working cluster/master?

Comment: Reapplying the network plugin should fix it caution the kubernetes networking will be down till the pods come up

Comment: Please answer my question and explain how to reapply network plugin (using flannel + ipvs)

Comment: I didn't use flannel but I will try out and answer in sometime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally when performing such a task like "replacing a node" below steps should be considered:

1. Drain node `kubectl drain NODE_NAME`
2. Reset that node `kubeadm reset` in the old node (optional step if the old node is accessible)
3. Finally `kubeadm delete node NODE_NAME`

Things to consider when replacing a old node with new node:

1. The new node should have the same name as the old node which is `echo $HOSTNAME` should remain same.
2. The new node should have the same ip as the old one.

Because these are a node identity.

Finally in a scenario where you have already performed `kubectl delete node ...` and replaced it with a new one.

```sh
curl -LO https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/62e44c867a2846fefb68bd5f178daf4da3095ccb/Documentation/kube-flannel.yml
kubectl delete -f kube-flannel.yml
```

[perform below in the nodes which are having problems]

```
sudo ip link del cni0
sudo ip link del flannel.1
sudo systemctl restart network
```

[re-apply network plugin]

```
kubectl apply -f kube-flannel.yml
```